# Magento 2 - Configurable Product Price

Tags: magento, magento2

I have problem with prices of configurable products on magento 2.

What I do:

I have configurable product with assigns simple products (by size).  I want change price and add specialprice to my configurable  product. On Magento 1  I can control prices from configurable product (price configurable product is priority). On Magento 2 configurable product is havn't a price. I must change prices on all simple products.  its is a annoying.
Its is possible to set price only in configurable products? All simple products associative to configurable product on my shop have this same price

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Only we can add price add QTY to child(simple) products. Configurable products not have those values in Magento 2 default.

If you want change that behaviour, you want to override core modules of Magento 2.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171452/magento-2-edit-price-field-in-configurable-product-in-admin-panel

Answer (score 0):

You can add parent product price while creating the configurable product using Advanced Price option. But once you have saved the configurable product you aren't able to change that parent product price. This is the magento 2 default behavior.

Also please go through this link to know price related scenarios in configurable product.

Link: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-magento-2-configurable-product-price.html

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOveflow! I think that it would be nice to give some context about the link, so if the link goes down, we still have some knowledge to share.